# RequireJS - define function is not returning dependencies correctly

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm using RequireJS and when I define a new module using the function "define" I see the dependencies were resolved but the objects are not the modules I defined.

All the modules are defined in AMD format, setting a name, array of dependencies and a function. The exportation is done by return an object.

The dependencies resolved by "define" have these properties: exports, id, packaged, and uri. If I then call require function the dependencies are set correctly.

**UPDATE: I created a test example with the described issue**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/require.js" data-main="../Scripts/main"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/module.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
require(["module"], function (module) {
    module.test();
});
```

module.js:

```
define([], function () {

    function test() {
        return "a";
    }

    return {
        test: test
    };
});
```

Console:
Uncaught TypeError: module.test is not a function

This happens because module is not resolved to the real module but to an object with properties:

-config { arguments: null, caller: null, length: 0, name: "config" }

-exports { id: "*@r5", uri: "../Scripts/*@r5.js" }

Setting a module name in the define function has the same result.

**NOTE: in the example there was an issue detected by @Louis. A module cannot be named "module". This helped me fixed the example but didn't fix my real issue. Below I describe the solution.**

**SOLUTION:**

My issue was related to a library called Ace (HTML editor). This is the link that helped me solve it: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/issues/173

Comment: What does your require config look like? How come you use `bConfig` at one place and `builderConfiguration` at another? Are they the same?

Comment: That was a typo in the question, I have already fixed it. I don't have a require config, is that mandatory? require functions resolves dependencies correctly so define should do it the same way. I'm using bundles to load the files.

Comment: No `define` should not, just because `require` does. You have to understand how `require.js` locates modules by settings it's `path`, either absolute or relative. If you do not receive a failure that `bConfig` module could not be loaded, or normalized to a module according to your `require.config` settings, then the only problem I can think of is that you have multiple `bConfig.js` files in your project directory. Doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: I don't have multiple bConfig.js files. No errors, the problem is how the objects are resolved to something else with the properties I specified in the question.

Comment: You won't get anything more than guesses until you edit the question with a [mcve]. I've used RequireJS for years, and I've never ever seen the behavior you describe, and there's nothing in the code currently in the question that would explain *why* you get the behavior you describe. (To answer a question in an earlier comment: you can absolutely run RequireJS without setting a configuration explicitly, if the defaults happen to be what you need.)

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein in other words, it would be very helpful if you update your question with the entrance code, e.g. if being run in a browser: `<script src="require.js" data-main="test"></script>`, the relevant source part of your entrance script (my example `test.js`) and of `bConfig.js`, which version of `require` and the relevant parts of the source locations in your projects directory structure. Also, a brief explenation of what is meant by `I'm using bundles to load the files` ..

Comment: I'm not using data-main attribute. I have a bundle with require.js and all the necessary JS files so they are all loaded in advance. I'm using RequireJS to define the modules and to resolve the objects that each module requires and avoid polluting the global scope. I'm using the latest version of RequireJS.

Comment: `they are loaded in advance` is pure speculation to us. Are all these "files" in the bundle AMD compatible? Are they registered with requires defined map? If so how? Do some modules export to window and if so, how do you export them in requires context without using requires configuration? Do you explicetely wrap each module? Are some named modules and some not? I could go one and ask questions all night but in return you should buy me something from my amazon wish list ..

Comment: I'm saying they are loaded in advance because they are merged in one big file so we don't need to download files based on "require" function. But yes, you're right, the code is executed as you require it. They are all AMD compatible. I'm not using a map, just define to define modules and require to resolve them. All the modules are defined with "define" and they have a name, just like I described it in the question.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein `require` does not `download` a file, it requires the `content` of a file. It doesn't matter where the file comes from. The only thing `require` is interested in is that the content of the required dependency is known. The `download` process is nothing more of an obstacle created by the environment it runs in to answer the question *`how` is require able to retrieve the content of a dependency*. My only explenation is that one of your modules is exporting the `module` object, instead of using `module.exports`, as in accidently `return module`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I added more information to the question and described how I do the export of each module.

Comment: I updated my question with a working example that shows the issue.

Answer (score 3):

With the edit you made, it is now possible to diagnose the issue. **Do not name any module *you* write with the name `module`, and the problem will go away.**

The name `module` is one of three reserved module names: `module`, `require` and `exports`. You should never name any of your own modules with these names.

When you ask RequireJS to load `module`, it is not loading your module. Instead, it simply returns an internal structure which is meant to provide *information about the current module*. It has fields like `id`, which gives the current module id (i.e. the module name) and `url` which gives the URL from which the module was loaded, and so on and so forth.

Comment: You are right about module generating a conflict and lead me to find the real issue in my project. I was referring a library called Ace (HTML editor) and there was a conflict with it). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after reading

> properties: exports, id, packaged, and uri.

I'm guessing, like @Louis said we would, that the example in the OP's question is not the example in the OP's (test-)project.

When defining a module, there are 2 (and lots of more) general ways of doing so.

On of them is explained in the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) titled `CommonJS`.

If a module is defined with

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {

   console.log(module);

});
```

then the 3rd argument `module` will indeed contain `exports, id and uri` as in.

```
{
   config: function config()
   exports: Object {  }
   id: "js/modules/handgrip/index.js?bust=1512509846564"
   uri: "js/modules/handgrip/index.js?bust=1512509846564&bust=1512509846564"
}
```

In order to "return" your module in the given context, you can `export` it with

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {

   // require a depedency already loaded in context
   var someDep = require('someDep1');

   module.exports = {
      // whatever this module is about ..
   }
});
```

Only if you define the module with a name, followed by dependencies, as in

```
define('thename', [ 'someDep1', 'seomDep2', 'etc..' ], function(dep1, dep2, ..) {

   // the arguments in this context are those listed in order as defined in the array (parameters)

}
```

you get your expected results ..

**-- update after edit**

Was in a Scrum-meeting, sorry ;) So it's quite clear, as @Louis wrote.

`module`, `exports` and `require` are reserved words.

The following have the same results

```
define(['require', 'exports', 'module'], function(require, exports, module) {
  console.log(module);
});

define(function(require, exports, module) {
  console.log(module);
});
```

Comment: I'm using the last option, define with module name and dependencies. I don't see why this would solve the issue I described. Why am I getting my modules with properties like exports, id, packaged, and uri instead of the real properties? and why when I use require(...) to get them explicitely it works?

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein Unless your code is top secret, no one is able to help you buddy ;)

Comment: It's not top secret :) it's a big project that was all in one file, I separated it into multiple files, defined modules and implemented RequireJS. It's hard to give you real code because it's a huge app. I thought it was gonna be good enough with my question.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein It was to be expected that it is a huge project. Though the module given in de dependency array should be known, in your example `bConfig`, the problem could be anywhere, but just an outtake of the code where it goes wrong, e.g. definitions in which order modules are declared and how they are exported (e.g. factory, etc), would be helpful. Are you the author of this bundle?

Comment: I added more information in the question. definition is in AMD format and exportation is done by returning an object. I didn't write most of the JS code, I just inherited it and I'm refactoring so developer don't need a month to understand it.

Comment: Ok, could you scan the bundle for the following? `require.config(` and `"packages":`. The thing is, `require.js` supports [CommonJS packages](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages), somewhere a configuration should be present .. else you wouldn't see the properties `id, uri, exports` and `packages`. And it sounds more like I'm dealing with `SystemJS` as with `RequireJS` to be honest ..

Comment: I added RequireJS to the project so I can confirm there's no require.config.

Comment: Can you check this http://jsfiddle.net/9H7Fd/? it's pretty similar to my issue, the console shows the same properties I get when I try to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: I updated my question with a working example that shows the issue.